# Set dynamic parameter in ga command in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics

I have something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, prod) in collectionData">
<a target="_blank" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Product: Name', 'Aply product', 'Product: Name');">
    <img src="{{prod.card_image}}" alt="">
</a>
```

And, i must replace 'Product: Name' for prod var

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, prod) in collectionData">
<a target="_blank" onclick="ga('send', 'event', '{{prod.ent}}: {{prod.name}}', 'Aply product', '{{prod.ent}}: {{prod.name}}');">
    <img src="{{prod.card_image}}" alt="">
</a>
```

But that syntax is incorrect to js. I'm trying the next syntaxis but doesn't works:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, prod) in collectionData">
<a target="_blank" onclick="ga('send', 'event', '' + prod.ent + ': ' + prod.name + '', 'Aply product', '' + prod.ent + ': ' + prod.name + '');">
    <img src="{{prod.card_image}}" alt="">
</a>
```

Any idea to set correctly the prod var?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `onclick` but use `ng-click` otherwise `prod-ent` and `prod.name` will be `undefined`. But when you do that, `ga` will turn out to be `undefined` because you're working in the directive's scope, not in window scope as `onclick` does. So you've got to inject `$window` in your controller, and assign `$window.ga` to your scope: `$scope.ga = $window.ga;` If you do so the following will work as you'de expect:

```
<a target="_blank" ng-click="ga('send', 'event', prod.ent + ': ' + prod.name, 'Aply product', prod.ent + ': ' + prod.name);">
    <img src="{{prod.card_image}}" alt="">
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. The problem is that I'm already using the ng-click directive for other features.

Comment: Then you should create a method in your controller where you can handle everything you want to do: `$scope.doStuff = function () { $window.ga(....); handleThis(); handleThat(); }` and then in your template: `ng-click='doStuff()'`

Comment: Or you could create a custom directive. Sounds like a good usecase